# Coefficients of the expansion of $\prod_{i=1}^k(x+i)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, terminology

This seems to be something well known, but I couldn't find any reference.

Suppose that we wish to expand the product $\prod_{i=1}^k(x+i)$ as $a_0x^k+a_{1}x^{k-1}+\ldots+a_{k-1}x+ a_k$. The coefficients of this expansion would be: 
$$\begin{aligned}
a_0={ }&1\\
a_1={ }&\sum_{i=1}^k i=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\\
a_2={ }&\frac{1}{2}\sum_{1\le i,j\le k\atop i\neq j}ij=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right)^2-\sum_{i=1}^k i^2\right]\\
\ldots\\
a_k={ }&\prod_{i=1}^k i=k!\end{aligned}$$
I wonder if there is a name and an expression for the coefficients $a_i$?

Comment: You may be interested in the [*Stirling numbers of the first kind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Comment: The answers are in [OEIS sequence A132393](https://oeis.org/A132393) "Triangle of unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind (see A048994), read by rows, T(n,k) for 0 <= k <= n."

Answer (score 3):

One way of looking at it is that the $a_i$ are the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Definition), $e_i(1,\dots, k)$,in $1,\dots, k$.